# Slow building angular 6 of webpack

Tags: angular, performance, webpack, build

My app migrate from Angular 4  to angular 6 and i switched VS15 to VS17 (stack of angular and asp.net core 2+). 
Before this dev build spend about 3 minutes. Now it's taking about 20-25 minutes.

I already tried change devtool to eval or false, also tried webpack-node-externals. Still same time.

Here is my configuration:

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"webpack-dev-server --env=dev --open --hot --inline --port 8080\" \"dotnet run\" ",
    "webpack-dev": "webpack --env=dev --progress --profile",
    "webpack-production": "webpack --env=prod",
    "build-dev": "npm run webpack-dev",
    "build-aot-production": "npm run webpack-production",
    "watch-webpack-dev": "webpack --env=dev --watch --color",
    "watch-webpack-production": "npm run build-production --watch --color",
    "publish-for-iis": "npm run webpack-production && dotnet publish -c Release",
    "build": "npm run webpack-production && dotnet publish -c Release",
    "build-prod": "npm run webpack-production && dotnet publish -c Release"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.8.1",
    "@angular/animations": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/common": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/core": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/forms": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/http": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/platform-server": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/router": "6.1.7",
    "@angular/upgrade": "6.1.7",
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.1",
    "ajv": "5.2.3",
    "angular2-modal": "3.0.3",
    "angular2-text-mask": "8.0.4",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "0.17.4",
    "ie-shim": "0.1.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "ng-select": "^1.0.1",
    "ngc": "^1.0.0",
    "pdfmake": "0.1.33",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "6.3.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "tslib": "1.7.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "3.2.12",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^6.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^10.9.4",
    "@types/express": "4.0.37",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.7",
    "angular-router-loader": "0.6.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.3",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "0.1.16",
    "concurrently": "3.5.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "css-loader": "0.23.1",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-loader": "0.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "last": "1.1.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "2.6.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "tslint": "4.5.1",
    "tslint-loader": "3.5.3",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "typings": "2.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "webpack": "4.19.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.8",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.9",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.1",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.5.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0"
  }
```

webpack.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const rxPaths = require('rxjs/_esm5/path-mapping');

const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackTools = require('@ngtools/webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');



const ROOT = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

console.log('-----------------------DEV BUILD:');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  entry: {
    app: './app/main.ts'
  },

  output: {
    path: ROOT + '/wwwroot/',
    filename: 'dist/[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html']
  },

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: path.join(ROOT, '/wwwroot/'),
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000
    }
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [
          'awesome-typescript-loader',
          'angular-router-loader',
          'angular2-template-loader',
          'source-map-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot|ico)$/,
        use: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]'
      },

      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: ['/node_modules/', '/fedresurs-app/css/'],
        loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: ['./fedresurs-app/css/'],
        exclude: ['/node_modules/'],
        loaders: ['style-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: 'raw-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
      }
    ],
    exprContextCritical: false
  },
  plugins: [
    function () {
      this.plugin('watch-run', function (watching, callback) {
        console.log(
          '\x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m',
          `Begin compile at ${new Date().toTimeString()}`
        );
        callback();
      });
    },

    new webpackTools.AngularCompilerPlugin({
      tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    }),

   ,

    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['./wwwroot/dist', './wwwroot/assets'], {
      root: ROOT
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      inject: 'body',
      template: 'app/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

tsconfig.json:

> ```
> {
>   "compilerOptions": {
>     "target": "es5",
>     "module": "es2015",
>     "moduleResolution": "node",
>     "sourceMap": true,
>     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
>     "experimentalDecorators": true,
>     "removeComments": true,
>     "noImplicitAny": false,
>     "skipLibCheck": true,
>     "noUnusedLocals": false,
>     "noUnusedParameters": false,
>     "lib": [
>       "es2015",
>       "dom"
>     ],
>     "typeRoots": [
>       "./node_modules/@types/"
>     ]
>   },
>   "exclude": [
>     "node_modules",
>     "./app/main-aot.ts",
>     "./app/app/main-aot.ts"
>   ],
>   "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
>     "useWebpackText": true
>   },
>   "files": [
>     "app/typings.d.ts"
>   ],
>   "compileOnSave": false,
>   "buildOnSave": false
> }
> ```

Builder told me that i have 1143  modules. And i get extremely slow dependencies build just look

```
app/app/app-routing.module.ts 3.24 KiB [built]
    |     [] 13483ms -> [] 232ms -> factory:24022ms building:7ms dependencies:196551ms = 234295ms
```

Comment: it is pretty interesting but i don't think that any1 give you right answer, you should try to exclude some libraries and modules and rerun build, problem is too specific

Comment: may be. I think someone could have a problem with slow dependencies build. Hope so.

Comment: now got some result. Roll back to "typescript": "2.5.2" and project start build with same time as usual (but a catched a error with angular 6 and typescript version)

Comment: check if your build is generating sourcemaps.... if so disable them `--source-map=false`

Answer (score 1):

As already said in the comments, this can be a very specific case but I will try to give you some hints, since I also did major updates (Angular 4 to 5, 5 to 6 and now 6 to 7) and came across some solutions that helped me.

---

**Check dependencies:**
As I can see in your dependencies, you have a lot of them. You can try to search where you need the dependencies and try to eliminate. If you find dependencies where you only need a small portion, you can try to remove and implement yourself.

Another tip is to make your import statements specific, like:
`import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';`

instead of

`import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material';`

This will help to decrease bundle size which is the next topic.

---

**Check bundle size:**
You can check the bundle size with `webpack-bundle-analyzer` to check what actually gets bundled. If you see suspicious large portions then you can research that. Also check how much styles are included.

**Edit**: Didn't see you already have that installed.

Install with `npm i webpack-bundle-analyzer --save-dev`.

Add following script to package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "bundle-report": "ng build --stats-json && webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"
  }
```

Finally run with `npm run bundle-report`

---

**Try different versions of @angular-devkit/core:**
At many places I read that using different versions of `@angular-devkit/core` helped to decrease build time. You can try to upgrade version by version and look at the build times and compare with each other.

---

**Additional personal tips:**

- Remove rxjs-compat and go to full rxjs version 6.
- Check for legacy dependencies from Angular 4 and remove them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! real problem was in strange work of awesome-typescript-loader. He was terribly slow in my case. May be because they dont update it for 2+ years. I migrated to ts-loader and now i'm spending 8-12 seconds for building.